# Redirect after download file - Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to redirect a page after downloading a file.
This is the code:

```
app.get('/log', function(req,res){
     return res.download('file.txt', function(err){
            if(!err){
                return res.render('index.html');
            }
        });
})
```

But every time i get this error:
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

There is another way to redirect/render after downloading? (At server-side, please).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in the way you think as the headers are already sent with the download response.

You can accomplish by manipulating the response yourself to send a required headers for file download and also send a location header along with. The requester should understand the location header and redirect accordingly.

for eg.

```
const fileData = /* read file */;
res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Location': '/'
});
res.end(fileData);
```

Comment: How would you code: 'send a location header along with'? What would be the code snippet for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the location header to the download response:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    res.set({
        'Location': "URL://for.redirection"
    });
    res.download("path/to/the/resource");
});
```